# Convert profile/contact into a QR code

Tags: android

I want to implement this feature into my application in which the respective persons profile/contact is automatically converted into a QR code.

Comment: Elementary OS Stack Exchange is the wrong place for programming and also you should tell us your programming language , platform ,etc. Repost this question on Stack Overflow and you will get an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I use [ZXING](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) library for all my QR code needs. It can encode and decode QR codes. After implementing it just read upon how to format [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard)